# Terms of $(t_1+t_2+...+t_n)^p$?

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Who could show me how many terms are in the expansion of
$$(t_1+t_2+...+t_n)^p$$
I totally confused myself and I cannot figure it out:-(

I was inspired by GDumphart. Thanks so much! It should be the number of options that $k_1+k_2+...+k_n = p$. The answer should be (n+p-1) choose (p).

Comment: This should help I think. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: I got it! Thanks so much! It should be the number of options that $k_1+k_2+...+k_n = p$.

Comment: I think the answer should be (n+p-1) choose (n). I wonder whether we have the same answer.

Comment: @Masacroso Take $n=2=p$. We know there are three terms. Which agrees with $\binom{n+p-1}{n}$. Your formula says $2(2-1)=2$ which is wrong.

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry see the edit. Correct answer is $\binom{n+p-1}{p}$

Comment: Ye, lol, I get confused... I read powers where just are different elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(t_{1}+t_{2}+\cdots+t_{n})^{p}=\sum_{k_{1}+\cdots+k_{n}=p}\frac{p!}{k_{1}!k_{2}!\ldots k_{n}!}t_{1}^{k_{1}}t_{2}^{k_{2}}\ldots t_{n}^{k_{n}}.$$ So there are $\binom{n+p-1}{p}$ terms = number of ways you can put $p$ identical balls into $n$ many cells.

*Clarification:* In how many ways can we write $k_{1}+k_{2}+\cdots+k_{n}=p$?. Where each $k_{i}$ is a non negative integer. It is exactly the number of possible ways to *put $p$ identical balls into $n$ cells*. Now treat $n$ cells as $n-1$ dividers. Then it is the number of permutations of $p$ *identical* balls and $n-1$ many *identical* dividers. Then the number of permutations is

$$\frac{(p+n-1)!}{p!(n-1)!}=\binom{p+n-1}{p}=\binom{p+n-1}{n-1}.$$

Comment: @Masacroso If you don't sum them up then you get $n^p$ terms.

Comment: @Indrajit Your formula should be $\binom{n+p-1}{p}$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks. See the edit.

Comment: @Masacroso see edits.